# Appending to CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I use a linear gradient on a background image on a site, but because I want to randomise the image I have to sprinkle in a bit of PHP logic.

See below.

```
<div class="jumbotron hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="headerhome" style="background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(166, 195, 206, 0.5), 
   rgba(166, 195, 206, 0.5)),
   linear-gradient(
   to bottom,
   rgba(64, 64, 64, 0) 70%,
   rgba(77, 78, 94, 0.5) 80%
    ), url('img/home/hero-img/hero-img-<?php echo $rand ?>.jpg');

    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(166, 195, 206, 0.5), 
    rgba(166, 195, 206, 0.5)),
    url('img/home/hero-img/hero-img-<?php echo $rand ?>.jpg');

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(166, 195, 206, 0.5), 
 rgba(166, 195, 206, 0.5)),
    url('img/home/hero-img/hero-img-<?php echo $rand ?>.jpg');

    background: -linear-gradient(rgba(166, 195, 206, 0.5), 
 rgba(166, 195, 206, 0.5)),
    url('img/home/hero-img/hero-img-<?php echo $rand ?>.jpg');

    background-blend-mode: multiply;">
```

Is there a way to have the styling for headerhome in a CSS file, then appending the URL segment with an inline style.

Essentially I'm trying to figure out a relatively clean way of doing this, as even though the current code is working, I have been told it isn't maintainable.

Given this, is it is necessary to define the gradient for every single browser?

Comment: This is a very nice question. I am trying to implement this using `inherit` but no luck till now.

Comment: If I manage anything further I'll re-post it.

Comment: I don't think it can be managed further. The only thing I think can be done is having different images in different classes (along with same gradients, with vendor prefixes) and switch those classes randomly using php or javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign image to `before` pseudo element, and get rid of implement image for every browser gradient set property.

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
.container:after {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;
  content: "";
  background: url('http://www.emtec-international.com/sites/default/files/sd4-2gb-largesize.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);">
</div>
```

Comment: It is actually other way, I mean the background image url should be in inline style and gradients in the class. Anyway, this will compromise the `background-blend-mode`. I don't know if OP is fine with it or not.